# Get Facebook feed from private group

Tags: php, facebook, parsing, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I had written my own script (with [official PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4)) which get groups feed using Facebook OpenGraph protocol. 
It works fine with public groups, but it doesn't work with private. 
It's possible to add for [my app](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) access to a private group (If my administration profile have access to group)?

Maybe exist other ways to get info about private groups?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group

Comment: And how I can solve my problem?

Comment: If you can't help don't write answer

Comment: my comments are VERY helpful. the facebook docs offer everything you need to know. your question suggests that you don´t know about access tokens and stuff, that´s exactly what you need to learn. did you even visit the link i posted?

Comment: I read this documentation page before posting question in SO. I don't know how I can use Graph API with User Access Tokens because my script running by cron and Facebook don't allow offline access. In other hand with App Token I haven't found how I get access to a private group that app admin have access.

Comment: @MisterG did you find away through this? trying to pull posts of a closed group which i am member at, using both my user token or an App id i am Admin on with no Luck, empty json everytime?

Answer (score 2):

You MUST use a User Token with the `user_groups` permission to read private groups. Now there are 2 problems with this:

- Even an Extended User Token is only valid for 60 days, so you would have to refresh the Token every 60 days - and you can´t do that with a cron job, you have to do it manually.
- It will only work for users with a role in the App. You will definitely not get `user_groups` approved by Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_groups

Edit: `user_groups` is gone, you can only use `user_managed_groups` now, so it is only possible with groups you manage.

Comment: But can I use user token between refresh in cron job? And second - It's means that FB manually grant this permission for apps and no ways to use `user_groups` with PHP SDK? Correct?

Comment: of course you can use the user token in a cron job while it is valid, you just can´t refresh it with a cron job.

Comment: about user_groups: it means that facebook will not approve it, so you can only use your app with users who got a role in the app (admin, developer, tester). but you can never go public with it. there´s no relation to the php sdk or any sdk at all.

Comment: Ok, I have tried work with User token and got this warning: [http://prntscr.com/674kkj]. it means that my script stop working on 30 April? Or I can use it without Facebook approving with app admin profile?

Comment: i´m afraid i cannot open that screenshot. but you can use any permission without approval as app admin.

Comment: yeah, that´s the default message for unapproved permissions. as i said, you would need to go through a review process with user_groups, but you will most likely not get it approved.

Comment: meaning, your app will never be able to go live, you can only use it as app admin

Comment: Understand that to release a public app we would need facebook to OK the permissions. But shouldn't I expect to be able to use the Facebook Graph API explorer (e.g. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=%7Bgroup-id%7D%2Ffeed) to test reading posts for a private group I created and am admin of? I am just getting back an empty JSON array [].

Comment: did you ask for the correct permission in the api explorer?

Comment: So it only works with group that you manage? If the group i'm a member?